# Creating a list of lists in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am new to Racket programming, and I am working on a problem where I am given a list of numbers, and I have to make a list of list, of different combinations of numbers.

Something like :

```
(combine (list 3 1 2))  => (list 
                           (list 31 32 33)
                           (list 21 22 3)
                           (list 11 12 13))
```

How do I achieve this in Racket?
Thank You

Comment: I think there's a typo in the expected output, it should be `(list 21 22 23)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just play with [iterators and comprehension](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html) to implement a cartesian product that returns lists of lists, and a bit of arithmetic to obtain the right results. Try this:

```
(for/list ((i '(3 2 1)))
  (for/list ((j '(1 2 3)))
    (+ (* 10 i) j)))
```

Or alternatively, using more standard constructs (available in student languages):

```
(map (lambda (i)
       (map (lambda (j)
              (+ (* 10 i) j))
            '(1 2 3)))
     '(3 2 1))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
=> '((31 32 33) (21 22 23) (11 12 13))
```

Comment: I have to use the Intermediate Student Language only. So are iterators allowed in ISL?

Comment: @Derik I don't think so, I updated my answer with a simpler alternative

Comment: @Derik I would say which language you are writing in is important information to be included in the question. It is normal to think that the tag `racket` means you have `#lang racket` while the `scheme` tag might indicate you are usng racket and writing in `#!r6rs`.

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without using iterators and map & lambda?

Comment: Sure, by doing the recursion by hand. Basically, you’d have to implement your own version of map, so don’t reinvent the wheel

Comment: How can I implement my own map? Sorry, if it is a dumb question, but I am having a tough time doing an assignment problem

Comment: A quick search in google will literally give you dozens of answers. Come on, you can do this on your own! It’s your task, after all.